# Wordpress 404 pagination (/page/2) error?

Tags: pagination, paginate-links

I have created custom post type for videos. Here is my code.

```
function video_register() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Video', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Video', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'video'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Video'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Video'),
        'new_item' => __('New Video'),
        'view_item' => __('View Video'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Videos'),
        'not_found' => __('Nothing found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'menu_icon' => null,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'custom-fields')
    );

    register_post_type('video', $args);
}
```

and I have displayed this video post at home page using this code.

```
$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
    $temp = $wp_query;
    $wp_query= null;
    $vcount = 20;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query();

        $wp_query->query('posts_per_page='.$vcount.'&post_type=video&paged='.$paged);
```

It all working fine. But its pagination is giving me 404 error when I hit to /page/2.

This pagination is showing me at homepage only. On category pages it is working fine. I did not understand what I have mistaken. 
I searched every where on internet but could not found any solution. Please suggest me what is wrong with my code.

Comment: as @Rarst said, you should be using `pre_get_posts`. You should never change the main query for a custom query on the homepage and any ype of arhive page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pagination cannot be reliably implemented in template. It is resolved during load way before template it ever reached.

Unless you implement it from scratch (complete with rewrite) you need to be using `pre_get_posts` or other related hook to modify main query. Look around the site, there are plenty answer on topic of here.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand your point

Comment: @johnmicky which is why you are up for a lot of research on topic to implement this properly. :) Please search the site for answers on how to use `pre_get_posts` for starters.

Answer (score 0):

Since you using this:  `get_query_var('page')`  Try this change of 'paged' to 'page' for the variable name.

```
$wp_query->query('posts_per_page='.$vcount.'&post_type=video&page='.$paged);
```

Comment: I used this, this is not worked